# Grep-like tool to show a specific region of a text relative to a pattern

Tags: grep, text-formatting

I have this kind of text message published at a high frequency:

```
pose: 
  - 
    position: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
  - 
    position: 
      x: 0.350104982508
      y: 0.729534356813
      z: -3.10228873344e-06
    orientation: 
      x: -9.84128404362e-07
      y: -1.996909502e-06
      z: -0.447019362477
      w: 0.894524281149
  - 
    position: 
      x: 0.455011
      y: -1.59228
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
```

I want to pipe it to grep or any other similar tool in order to show the area starting from 12 lines after "pose:" until 20 lines after "pose:".
The basic commands for grep only allow to show n lines before or after "pose:", In my case what I want to display is this submessage:

```
position: 
  x: 0.350104982508
  y: 0.729534356813
  z: -3.10228873344e-06
orientation: 
  x: -9.84128404362e-07
  y: -1.996909502e-06
  z: -0.447019362477
  w: 0.894524281149
```

Is there any command line tools that can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 awk '/^pose:/{s=NR+11} (NR>s && NR<s+10){print $0}'
```

When line start with `pose:`, `s` is set as `NR+11`. if `NR` is greater than `s` and less than `s+10` lines are printed.

Answer (score 1):

Answer REPLACED:

Basically it's the matter of substraction of '5 lines after' from 'all 20 lines after'

here's my quick suggestion

`diff <(grep 'pose:' filename -A 20)  <(grep 'pose:' filename -A 5)`

Of course diff output will contain
some extra headings lines and '<' sign, which you may want to filter out

that's however no big deal to filter out

Comment: I don't understand how the -B can be applied here, can you please clarify?

Comment: I am sorry for overlooking the point.
I'll update the answer soon

Comment: this command is using a text file though, I have a program continuously outputting text and need to pipe its output.

Answer (score 0):

```
(grep -A 20 "pose:" file; echo "--")|grep -B 9 '^--'
```

Comment: can you pipe that?